# How to setup caching for specific headers in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I'm unsure if this is even possible. I'm making requests to an external api and on each request from my app I pass the user's query into a custom `'query'` header in the Cloud Function (Typescript). ⤵

```js
export const searchQuery = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

    // : Reads request query data from user
    const query = request.headers.query;

...
```

I attempted to setup caching so that with each query it caches the result separately but it doesn't seem to be working. ~

*( caching does work without vary header set however it's only caching the first search result ) 

( all requests are sent as `GET` )*

This is the block that sets the `'query'` header as a vary rule for caching (written in Typescript). ⤵

```js
...

    return await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId) // : Authenticates response
        .then(() => {

            // : Set cache-control
            console.log(request.headers);
            response.set('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding, query');
            response.set("Cache-Control", "public, s-maxage=600");
            response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");

            // : Grab API search data
            axio.get(urlAssembler).then(APIData => {
                response.status(200).send(APIData.data);
            }).catch(error => console.log(error));

        })
        .catch((err) => response.status(401).send(err));

...
```

I have this setup on Cloud Functions w/ Firebase and not Cloud Functions with Firebase Hosting. I'm wondering if maybe there's a difference there but it seems there isn't.

In my `firebase.json` I noticed that it is setup for Cloud Functions and not for Firebase Hosting. Perhaps I need to set it up as Firebase Hosting to define cache-control for headers there?

*This is my firebase.json ⤵*

```js
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Firebase support regarding this and the individual helping me said that **Firebase Hosting** needs to be used in order to cache based on a header like described above.

I have not tested this yet so once I test it I will update this answer to confirm that it works.

There is an article suggested to me by the individual helping me from Firebase support for how to [cache **within** a Cloud Function](https://yvonnickfrin.dev/how-to-add-cache-to-your-gcp-cloud-functions) but I don't believe this makes use of a CDN.

Comment: I didn't get the part *Firebase Hosting needs to be used*. I have hosting deployed along with functions but still doesn't work :/
Can i get a working example, if you have one?

Comment: Hi Anna, I still haven't tried this out yet. From what  I understand, if you have hosting and functions setup properly then you should be able to determine cache behavior based on a request header you specify --> https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache